# Use value as scalar field in Marching Cubes node (Sverchok addon)

Tags: sverchok

I am trying to use the marching cubes node (in the sverchok addon) with a set of points as follows:

[image]

So, I have a set of points with xyz coordinates, and “w” values at each of these coordinates. I would like to use the xyz coordinates of these points as the bounds, and the w values as the scalar field.

What I don’t understand so far is, how to convert the w values into a scalar field that is usable by the marching cubes node? Any ideas how to convert the w values to a scalar field?

Here is a zip with the set of points and blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h4F8KKpS4NqOUjcxeR3y-JS_zq5zGncU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: scalar field is XYZ as i understand.

Comment: bounds can be added with separate BOX node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. to make scalar field use XYZ and W.
2. Bounds can be as Box node generator or any other simple geometry creating square
3. Follow screenshot

[image]

or even this:

[image]